# Getting WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server when doing controller call with SSL enabled asp.net core 2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have an app published to Azure Portal that is ASP.net core 2 and SSL enabled. 
When I am doing a controller call to that app I am getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebSockets.WinHttpWebSocket.ThrowOnInvalidConnectState()

WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle+<ConnectAsyncCore>d__20.MoveNext()
```

My Controller method looks like this:

```
    public async Task SendAsync(string msg)
    {
        dynamic newEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(msg);
        TUKUEventSQL newSQLEvent = new TUKUEventSQL();
        newSQLEvent.TTID = newEvent.TTID;
        newSQLEvent.TTUID = newEvent.TTUID;
        newSQLEvent.UTC = newEvent.UTC;
        newSQLEvent.Event = newEvent.e;
        newSQLEvent.Object = newEvent.o;
        newSQLEvent.ObjectId = newEvent.id;

        // Trasform
        NudestixEvent newDataMartRecord = eventToNudestixTransformer.TransformInputToNudestixEvent(newSQLEvent);

        //Send
       connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
           .WithUrl($"http://{Request.Host}/chat")
           .WithConsoleLogger()
           .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();
        await connection.InvokeAsync("Send", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newDataMartRecord));
    }
```

And exception stacks:

```
WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.WebSockets.WinHttpWebSocket.ThrowOnInvalidConnectState()
System.Net.WebSockets.WinHttpWebSocket+<ConnectAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle+<ConnectAsyncCore>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

You url says `http`, maybe you should change that to `https`? Please also check that the whole Url is correctly pointing to your server.

Though generally it's not the best way to call your own code. You can just use a direct method rather than calling your own web application from one of the controller.

Comment: Are you calling the same controller method from inside itself? Looks like it, I honestly don't know what is the possible outcome of this. Maybe you can describe better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Nope, it will be Http call from Azure Function

Comment: Have you checked that full url is correct? Try logging the url before it's being accessed and then paste it in the browser.